# Can we find the functional for a quantum field in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, path-integral, second-quantization

I've heard that QFT is really described by a functional which dictates the probability that a field will be in a certain configuration $\Phi[\phi]$. My question is, can we find an equation that will give us this functional, like in normal quantum mechanics we have the klein gordon equation and also the dirac. The first way that I could think about doing this is using the path integral $K(\phi';\phi)$ and then since this is a green function:

$$\Phi[\phi]=\int_{\phi_0}^{\phi} d[ \phi'] K(\phi';\phi_0)\Phi[\phi_0]$$

Im not sure this is the right way to go about it. I'm just trying to find a functional differnetial equation that gives $\Phi[\phi]$.

Comment: What you're looking for is the Schwinger-Dyson equation. In practice, you're not going to be able to find solutions though. Only real exception is the vacuum of a free theory, which is a Gaussian (act annihilation operators on it).

Comment: @RichardMyers is there a sort of probability current for this equation? Like an equivalent to the probability current in the Dirac equation and Schrodinger equation. However, I t would instead be in terms of the field configuration.

Comment: @JoshuaPasa In QFT, people usually focus on correlation functions (usually vacuum expectation values) because they're more amenable to good approximations. But we can write a "Schrödinger equation" for $\Phi[\phi]$ like I showed in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/542253) for a scalar field, and we can solve it using an explicit form for your $K(\phi';\phi_0)$ like I illustrated in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631829) for QED. (I used the letter $\Psi$ instead of $\Phi$.)

Comment: To add a keyword to @ChiralAnomaly's comment, you are looking for the [functional Schrodinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_functional) (the bibliography on that page is also a good starting point).

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19968/vacuum-wavefunctional).